# Is there a way to auto check the check-box 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' for all excel files?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

Right now, every time I need open a new/existing Microsoft Excel workbook, I find that in:

> Developer > Visual Basic > Tools > References

I have to manually scroll down the list to check the 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' so I can use the Macro functions which is a pain in the arse.

[image]

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: One way is to use late binding so that you won't need to add the library reference.

Comment: This may help https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother/set-default-references-for-all-vba-projects/23f196d0-d168-40f1-a64b-b549dd7df073